# How to access minutes of isodate field mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, isodate

I have a mongodb database where each row of the document has a date field (format ISO date).

I am trying to access hours and minutes in the date field and, for each minute of each hour, show the number of rows (notice that can be multiple rows for a minute). The output would be something like this:

```
11:20   5
11:41   1
13:20   8
15:30   11
```

Where the first column is the time (hour:minutes), and the second column the number of rows corresponding that time.

This is the command I am executing in mongodb:

```
db.user.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {hora: {$hour: '$created_at'}, minuto: {$minute: '$created_at'}}, total: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

where 'hora' is the field showing the hour and 'minuto' the field showing minutes.

This is the message I get:

[image]

This is how the isodate format looks:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not storing the date as `ISODate`, but rather as a string with ISODate format.

When you run the `find` query, it should be showing
`"created_at" : ISODate("2016-11-01T11:46:03.000Z")`

and not:

`"created_at" : "2016-11-01T11:46:03.000Z"`

**The code you have written is correct.**

**You will need to convert your strings to ISODates.**

You can fire this query in your mongoshell:

```
db.user.find().forEach(function(doc){
    doc.created_at = new Date(created_at)
    db.user.save(doc);
})
```